# "Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly"

Tags: python, typeerror

```
>>> def main():
        fahrenheit = eval(input("Enter the value for F: "))
        celsius = fahrenheit - 32 * 5/9
        print("The value from Fahrenheit to Celsius is " + celsius)
>>> main()
Enter the value for F: 32
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#73>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "<pyshell#72>", line 4, in main
    print("The value from Fahrenheit to Celsius is " + celsius)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: **Do not ever use `eval` for data that could possibly ever come from user input. It is a critical security risk that allows the user to run arbitrary code on your computer.**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`floats` can't be implicitly converted into strings. You need to do it explicitly.

```
print("The value from Fahrenheit to Celsius is " + str(celsius))
```

But it's better to use `format`.

```
print("The value from Fahrenheit to Celsius is {0}".format(celsius))
```

Comment: If you're using Python 2.7+ you can omit the positional argument specifiers in `str.format`, so `{0}` is equivalent to `{}`

Comment: _"But it's better to use `format`."_ Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you cannot covert float object to string implicitly. You have to do :

```
print("The value from Fahrenheit to Celsius is " + str(celsius))
```